# Phone book list formatting

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.3

I have a lot of trouble trying to figure this out.

I have seen lots of people show complex (complex for me) ways of fixing these columns but i have no idea how i could do it in this, as i am using a dictionary.

Any way, here's the code:

```
  elif menu==2:
    print("NAME=================PHONE NUMBER===")
    for x in book.keys():
        s=1
        p=s+1
        print(str(p)+")",x,"\t\t",book[x])
        s=p
```

Also if there is anything else i am doing that could be more efficient, please tell me as i am very new to python. And i can give you more code if needed.

*Edit*

Sorry, I didn't explain very well, the output i want is something like:

```
NAME===================PHONE NUMBER
John                   0425111222
Alexander              81238211
Firstand Lastname      99938880
```

Thanks,

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
i = 1
print('{0:2s} {1:15s} {2}'.format('#', 'Name', 'Number'))
for name, number in book.items():
    print('{0:<2d} {1:15s} {2}'.format(i, name, number))
    i += 1
```

It is simple and clear.

An example output:

```
#  Name            Number
1  Contact1        555
2  Contact2        777
```

Comment: Looks like i have a lot to learn... Could you explain what the braces and format function in the first print statement do? (and the second)
Also, does the `book.items():` need to be items or is that a general thing.

Comment: You should learn output formatting and dictionary (methods like items()) to understand this code clearly.